# How can I add a type parameter to my DAL's implementation of ExecuteScalar?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ado.net

So as everyone knows, .NET's `SqlClient` class offers as a way of getting data from the database the `ExecuteScalar` method, which returns an `object`.  While it's not a big deal to just cast appropriately, I wanted to write a strongly typed version that returns a properly typed object.  So, I wrote the following C#:

```
public T ExecuteScalar<T>(IDbCommand cmd) where T : struct
{
    cmd.Connection = this.conn;
    object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return (T)o;
}
```

This works very well for booleans and `DateTime`s.  However, for integers, it throws an `InvalidCastException`.  So, I did what anyone armed with a copy of Reflector would do and dove into the `Field<T>(this DataRow, string columnName)` extension method.  I ripped out the internal class that it uses to convert values to the requested type and tested.  However, for value types, the code is just `return (T)value;` - which is of course not helpful.

So, my question: anyone have any thoughts about how I can get my method to properly return values for all value types and strings?  Even just string, boolean, `DateTime` and int would be fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI: `string` is a reference type.

Comment: Also, if the query doesn't return a result, that could cause the casting error.

Comment: Indeed it is, thanks.  And no, the query's definitely returning a result - I executed the ones that were resulting in this exception by hand and they work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is returning a boxed instance of a different numeric type (probably `decimal`).

[You cannot unbox it and convert it to `int` in one operation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx).

Instead, you can call `Convert.ChangeType`:

```
return o is t ? (T)o : (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the cast should be OK, if the value returned is in fact an integer.

Perhaps your database returns NULL ? In that case, o will be `DBNull.Value`, which you will have to take into account before casting. An easy way would be to use `int?`, or you could decide to throw an exception in that case.

If null is not the issue, then try posting the concrete type of o after the ExceuteScalar call.

Answer (score 0):

If the object returned was not an integer (if it is a float, double, byte, etc) it was boxed to an object and can only be cast back to its original type.  check the type of `o`.